# Why is there an option of AnyType when creating a buttons action

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, action

When creating a `UIBUttons` action, the default is AnyType. Why is it default, and why is it an option at all? Shouldn't it just be  UIButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can hook *any* sort of `UIControl` up to an `IBAction` method.  Additionally, we can hook up `UIGestureRecognizers` to `IBAction` methods.

If we do connect multiple things up to this method, it has to take an argument type that works for everything that could possibly be sent in.

So, if we hook up a `UIButton` and a `UIGestureRecognizer` to an action, the only thing that works is if the argument it takes is an `AnyObject`.

Comment: As for why `AnyType` is the default over `UIButton`... I'm not sure anyone but Apple can answer that question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So basically, `IBActions` aren't specifically for buttons, so that's why it had to have `AnyObject`. This way we can hook up other things. Correct?

Comment: Right.  `IBAction` just means you're declaring a method that interface builder things can connect to.  `UIGestureRecognizers` and *all* `UIControl` subclasses can hook into `IBAction` methods.